# Using scanner to recognize both integers and strings, and stopping user input if a certain string is inputted

Tags: java, string, integer, java.util.scanner

Trying to use scanner to recognize both integers and strings, and stopping user input if a certain string is inputted.

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of students");
int numberof = myObj.nextInt();
```

Need to make it so if the user types "end", the scanner no longer takes user input. I can't put the line int numberof = myObj.nextInt(); in a loop or something and limit the variable scope, as i'm using that value of numberof throughout the rest of my code.

Comment: What if the user types "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"? Hint: You'll get an exception....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner#next and then parse integers if needed. I wouldn't recommend just directly using Scanner#nextInt.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
  System.out.println("Enter number of students");
  String next = sc.next();
  if (next.equals("end")) break;
  else {
    try {
      int num = Integer.parseInt(next);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
    }
  }
} while (true);
```

Comment: if I use that, in that scenerio the scope of the integer num would be limited, and I would need to access it throughout my code.

Comment: @Kai You can always declare it outside